# Why are my cucumbers deformed?

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, diseases, cucumbers

I'm growing a pickling variety of cucumber. Normally they grow in very predictable "pickle" shapes. A couple of weeks ago, I notice that most were oblong and sort of hooked.

In the photo below, the one at the top is normal for these seeds. The four below are exhibiting the strange misshapen issue that I'm investigating.

In the week or two since I took the photo, the newer cucumbers don't seem to be doing this anymore.

What causes this to happen?

[image: Cucumbers with assymetric shapes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience this is caused by lack of water coupled with hot weather.  To get a consistently-size cucumber it needs to have a steady water supply while the fruit is growing.

These look as though there was a hot and dry spell just as the fruit was starting and then more water later as the rest of the fruit developed.

Comment: That was my hunch. The weather was very hot and dry a week before I noticed this.